# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException while connecting database from spring boot application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, privileges

I have PostgreSQL database form there I have created database and 
    user using below commands.

```
create database webreporting;   
create user csr with password 'csrtest12!@';    
grant all on  database webreporting to csr;    
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES
    IN SCHEMA public to csr;    
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN
    SCHEMA public TO csr;    
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN
    SCHEMA public TO csr;
```

I am trying connect this database from springboot application. Spring boot application is started     successfully but while executing    the query from application it's throwing exception like below

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>       PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [Delete from facts where 
>       customer_id=?]; nested exception is   
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for
>       table    facts.

`Application.properties` file is:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver   
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webreporting 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect   
spring.datasource.username=csr   
spring.datasource.password=csrtest12!@
```

I am not sure why I am getting permission denied exception.

Comment: Has your user login privileges? Try `ALTER ROLE <username> WITH LOGIN;`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing permissions on schema.
Try running below command:

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO csr;
```

Comment: Is that table already created or you're expecting it to be created on startup?

Comment: its startup after this i want to create table

Comment: If you want your JPA entities to be created on startup, you need to set `ddl-auto` property in Spring configuration - [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html). Also, try to set the schema of your entity to `public`.